# Why MySQL doesn't use my primary key to join my table?

Tags: mysql, join, key, explain

I try to do a `SELECT` but I don't know why MySQL doesn't join my table with `INNER JOIN` on the primary key. He uses my foreign key instead...

My query :

```
SELECT cpte.* 
FROM tcomptes cpte
INNER JOIN tentreprises_acteurs tentGest ON tentGest.nEntrepriseActeur = cpte.nGestionnaire
INNER JOIN tsites s on s.nSite = cpte.nSite
```

The problem is on the `INNER JOIN` of the table `tsites`.
There is the result of `EXPLAIN` instruction below :

[image: result of EXPLAIN]

Key uses by `tsites` table is a foreign key

Can you help me please ?

Comment: Why should it use the primary key? The join condition uses `s.nSite`, which is the foreign key.